# Is there an English term for clerks that frequently work outside the office?

Tags: vocabulary

Is there an English term for clerks that frequently work outside the office? Google Translate suggests it's “field clerk” but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Thank you.

Comment: You're probably going to have to clarify what you mean by "clerks that work outside the office". Are you referring to remote working, health inspectors or something else?

Comment: I mean clerks that have to run errands frequently, such as going to the post office, submitting hard copies of documents to various government departments or liaising with vendors. Does such a term exist in English or do you simply call them all clerks?

Comment: The term "outdoor clerk" exists in some law offices, or did when I was doing work experience 30 years ago. These days when most things can be done online I wonder if it's still a specific job.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel!

Answer (score 2):

In more informal conversation, you can refer to someone who just does random errands with no defined role as a gofer. However, this is not limited to people who leave the office and can be used to people who just stay in the office.

Otherwise, we tend to refer to people by their job title, so if they're called a clerk, then we would just call them a clerk. Just having tasks that require leaving the office briefly isn't considered something special. A person who primarily has an out-of-office task would tend to have a job title that reflects that (for example, a person who primarily delivers documents would have the job title of "courier" instead.) A "field clerk" would be a clerk who works in a field office (or a location that isn't the main office).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! 